# how to zoom in a page without displaying scroll in the parent component(main component) of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, scrollbar

I want to build a page that looks like the window application. There is a problem with this that when I zoom-in the page it will display a scroll-bar on the main page.
I set the parameters of the main page (the parent) as below.
width: 100vw,
height: 100vh

what should I do To scroll through the component inside the main page(the children components) instead of the main page(the parent component).
I put my the css part of my code below.

first css code of the main page(parent). I use Material-ui for styling. root is the className of the main page. header,breadeCrumb and content are className of my children components.

const useStyles = makeStyles({

```
root: {
    width:'100vw',
    height: '100vh',
},

header: {
    height: '10%',
},

breadCrumb: {
    height: '10%',
},

content: {
    height: '80%',
}
```

});

The content component also has its own children (sidebar and content) which I put their css properties below.

const useStyles = makeStyles({

```
root: {
    border: '1px solid blue', 
    display: 'flex',
    width:'auto',
    height: 'auto',
},

sidebar: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    width: '20%',

    height: 'auto',
    border: '1px solid red',
    overflow: 'scroll'
},

content: {
    height: 'auto',
    width: '80%',
}
```

});

Is there something that I forgot to set? please guide me to solve this problem if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should do these items ...

1. in your page(or the higher container component) style your root :

height:"100vh" -> this will fill whole screen.

2. and again in that container, style your children components :

in the way that some of all the heights be 100%

3. at the end, in each child component, the height must be:

height: '100%' -> to fit in the page

Answer (score 1):

This page on how to hide the scroll bar but keep the scrolling functionality from w3schools might be helpful:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

```
 /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

You could apply this to your `.root` class (or the `html` or `body` in your .css file) to hide the scrollbar on the root element or page when a user zooms in.

If you want only e.g. your Content element or Sidebar elements to scroll, you will need to set their height. `auto` will adjust height to accommodate the content. Try setting it with `px` or `vh`.

Here's a quick fiddle I made with some options for how to hide the scrollbar at the page level, but show it in a Sidebar and Content element: https://jsfiddle.net/bethylogism/b6nuehqg/246/

If this isn't quite what you're getting at, make a quick JS Fiddle or CodePen of the functionality you're struggling with. It will be easier to diagnose and help you. E.g. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "the window application".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it did not work for me. The good news is I could solve it and I put it here.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I solve the problem and I am goning to share it here.

As I told, I want my page to not be scrolled, but the components inside it should be scrolled by zooming-in. When I set the main page's width and height to 100vw and 100vh, I can give the width and height of components inside it with percentage to fit them in the page. The below code is the css for the main page.

I want to build a page that looks like the window application. There is a problem with this that when I zoom-in the page it will display a scroll-bar on the main page. I set the parameters of the main page (the parent) as below. width: 100vw, height: 100vh

what should I do To scroll through the component inside the main page(the children components) instead of the main page(the parent component). I put my the css part of my code below.

first css code of the main page(parent). I use Material-ui for styling. root is the className of the main page. header,breadeCrumb and content are className of my children components.

const useStyles = makeStyles({

root: {

```
width:"100vw",
height:"100vh",
```

},

header: {

```
height: "10%",
width: "100%",
```

},

breadCrumb: {

```
height: "10%",
width: "100%",
```

},

content: {

```
height: "80%",
width: "100%"
```

},
});

And the Content component's css code which consists of two components(Sidebar and content) is below.

const useStyles = makeStyles({

root: {

```
display: "flex",
width:"100%",
height:"100%",
```

},

sidebar: {

```
width: "20%",
height: "100%",
overflow: "auto",
```

},

content: {

```
width: "80%",
height: "100%",
overflow: "auto",
```

},

});